# Model View ViewModel in WPF with WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, mvvm, browser

Im writing an app in WPF using MVVM pattern, where Im restricted to binding to properties and commands exclusivley

However, I want to use the WebBrowser control which can only take an html string for content as a parameter to a mthod, and not a property.

I was going to create a new control derived from Webbrowser that has the required property, but the control class is sealed. I tried creating a wrapper control, but I had all sorts of problems with dependency properties that seemed to be more trouble solving than I could be bothered with.

Is there any way I can push a parameter(string) into a method with MVVM without resorting to code in the code-behind files (which is a big no-no).

Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 18):

Why is any code in the code-behind files a **no go**? I believe this is one of the most seen misunderstandings in the MVVM community.

**MVVM is not a pattern to eliminate the code behind**. It is to separate the view part (appearance, animations, etc.) from the logic part (workflow). Furthermore, you are able to unit test the logic part.

I know enough scenarios where you have to write code behind because data binding is not a solution to everything. Sample applications that use code behind and still fulfill the MVVM separation can be found here:

[**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 10):

I used the solution found here

[databind the Source property of the WebBrowser in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265648/285795)

HTH

Comment: Yep, an attached property is the easies way to make binding possible on a non-dependency property

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question (you want to call a method on the WebBrowser, but need an html string to do so?).

MVVM isn't about avoiding code-behind like the plague as much as it's about relegating code-behind files to strictly UI tasks.

If you set up your UI to include a typical Address Bar + Go button, you'll want to use the Buttons' Click handler to pass the string to the browser. Alternatively, the string could be a property of the ViewModel and you could collect it easily by binding it to the Tag property of the WebBrowser.

Your UI will appear roughly like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="addressBar" /> <!-- If you use the address bar -->
<Button Content="Go" Click="NavigateButton_Click" />
<WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Tag="{Binding URL}" />  <!-- If you bind to a VM property -->
```

Your code-behind could look like this:

```
void NavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   browser.Navigate(new Uri(addressBar.Text)); // Address Bar
   browser.Navigate(new Uri(browser.Tag.ToString()); // Tag Binding
}
```