# Is there an MVVM-friendly way to use the WebBrowser control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, mvvm, webbrowser-control

Thanks to [this question (click me!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263551), I have the `Source` property of my `WebBrowser` binding correctly to my ViewModel.

Now I'd like to achieve two more goals:

1. Get the `IsEnabled` property of my Back and Forward buttons to correctly bind to the `CanGoBack` and `CanGoForward` properties of the `WebBrowser`.
2. Figure out how to call the `GoForward()` and `GoBack()` methods without resorting to the code-behind and without the ViewModel having to know about the `WebBrowser`.

I have the following (non-working) XAML markup at the moment:

```
<WebBrowser
    x:Name="_instructionsWebBrowser"
    x:FieldModifier="private"
    clwm:WebBrowserUtility.AttachedSource="{Binding InstructionsSource}" />

<Button
    Style="{StaticResource Button_Style}"
    Grid.Column="2"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=_instructionsWebBrowser, Path=CanGoBack}"
    Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"
    Content="&lt; Back" />

<Button
    Style="{StaticResource Button_Style}"
    Grid.Column="4"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=_instructionsWebBrowser, Path=CanGoForward}"
    Command="{Binding GoForwardCommand}"
    Content="Forward &gt;" />
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that `CanGoBack` and `CanGoForward` are not dependency properties (and don't implement `INotifyChanged`), but I'm not quite sure how to get around that.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to hook up attached properties (as I did with `Source`) or something similar to get the `CanGoBack` and `CanGoForward` bindings to work?
2. How do write the `GoBackCommand` and `GoForwardCommand` so they are independent of the code-behind and ViewModel and can be declared in markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this in my bindable webbrowser wrapper:

```
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseBack, BrowseBack, CanBrowseBack));
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseForward, BrowseForward, CanBrowseForward));
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseHome, GoHome, TrueCanExecute));
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.Refresh, Refresh, TrueCanExecute));
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.BrowseStop, Stop, TrueCanExecute));
```

Note that I created my bindable webbrowser as FrameworkElement that exposes DependencyProperties and calls methods on the actual browser element, so i can set CommandBindings on it.

That way, you can use the default NavigationCommands in your View.
The used handlers are:

```
private void CanBrowseBack(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = webBrowser.CanGoBack;
}

private void BrowseBack(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    webBrowser.GoBack();
}

private void CanBrowseForward(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = webBrowser.CanGoForward;
}

private void BrowseForward(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    webBrowser.GoForward();
}

private void TrueCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) { e.CanExecute = true; }

private void Refresh(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    try { webBrowser.Refresh(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { PmsLog.LogException(ex, true); }
}

private void Stop(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WebBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
    if (doc != null)
        doc.execCommand("Stop", true, null);
}
private void GoHome(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    Source = new Uri(Home);
}
```

Comment: @Botz, thank you. I'm a little hazy on how you actually set up your `FrameworkElement` class. I assume you have a field `webBrowser`, but how do you actually get it to display? I was thinking I'd need to build a `UserControl` and actually place the `WebBrowser` in, say, a `Grid` on the control. How do you handle this with a class that inherits `FrameworkElement`? Thanks.

Comment: You don't actually need a UserControl, a FrameworkElement is just fine as long as you set it up correctly. My implementation might not be the best, but if you want to have a look, the control can be found here: http://pastebin.com/m492dbd3f (if you wonder about BrowserViewModel, it's the ViewModel the control's properties are actually bound to, i'm sure you already have your own ViewModel though)

Comment: // btw If you derive from FrameworkElement, you can call AddVisualChild and AddLogicalChild to actually put the WebBrowser or anything else inside it

Comment: @Botz, Ahh, nice, thanks. It's working inside my window right now. I just need a clue on how to bind to the NavigationCommands.BrowseBack. I've tried `Command="{Binding ElementName=_instructionsWebBrowser, Path=NavigationCommands.BrowseForward}"` and `Command="{Binding NavigationCommands.BrowseForward}"` so far and had no luck. Thanks again!

Comment: @Botz, I also tried simply `Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward"`, but that isn't working either.

Comment: Actually, those are built-in commands. They work anywhere in your application and are bound dynamically to the bindings that are in effect for the Element currently in focus. That also means different controls can each implement this command on their own and depending on which one has the focus, that implementation is used.
Just use them like this: 

`Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward"` 
For things like MenuItems, even the Text is set automatically just by doing that.

Comment: Oh! Yeah, one thing was missing. 

CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=_instructionsWebBrowser}"

Comment: @Botz3000: Would you mind dropping the control back on pastebin for a few days,  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes across this question and wants a complete solution, here it is. It combines all of the suggestions made in this thread and the linked threads (and others those link to).

XAML:
http://pastebin.com/aED9pvW8

C# class:
http://pastebin.com/n6cW9ZBB

Example XAML usage:
http://pastebin.com/JpuNrFq8

Note: The example assumes your view binds to a ViewModel that provides the source URL to the browser.  A very rudimentary navigation bar with back, forward, and refresh buttons and address bar is provided just for demonstration.

Enjoy. I have set the expiration on those pastebin's to never, so they should be available for as long as pastebin exists.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I was wondering what the _SkipSourceChange is there for?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply that in order to correctly implement an MVVM pattern you are not allowed to have any code-behind. But perhaps adding some code-behind to your view will make it much easier to hook it up with your view-model. You can add dependency properties to the view and let it listen for `INotifyPropertyChanged` events.