# DependencyProperty BindableSource cannot be set on an object of type Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser WP8

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, dependency-properties

I'm trying to add a DependencyProperty to my WebBrowser control in my WP8 app so that I can bind the source to a property within my ViewModel.

I found this thread on StackOverflow [databind the Source property of the WebBrowser in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263551/databind-the-source-property-of-the-webbrowser-in-wpf)

Since this applied to WPF, I've had to make a few changes to behaviour code (nothing major):

```
public class WebBrowserBehaviors : Behavior<WebBrowser>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();         
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
    "BindableSource",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(WebBrowserBehaviors),
    new PropertyMetadata(BindableSourcePropertyChanged)
    );

    public static void SetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser == null) return;

        Uri uri = null;

        if (e.NewValue is string)
        {
            var uriString = e.NewValue as string;
            uri = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uriString) ? null : new Uri(uriString);
        }
        else if (e.NewValue is Uri)
        {
            uri = e.NewValue as Uri;
        }

        browser.Source = uri;
    }
}
```

The thread also provide a XAML sample:

```
<WebBrowser ns:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding WebAddress}"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
Width="300"
Height="200" />
```

But I'm having 2 problems:

1. Problem 1:

   I declared my namespace as follows:

   `xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyApp.Behaviors"`

   My WebBrowser control is defined as follows and I've removed my `Source={Binding CurrentUri}` and replaced it by `behaviors:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource`.

   ```
   `<Grid Grid.Row="0" >
       <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"
           behaviors:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource="{Binding ...}"
           IsScriptEnabled="True" 
           NavigationFailed="webBrowser_NavigationFailed" 
           Navigating="webBrowser_Navigating" 
           LoadCompleted="webBrowser_LoadCompleted" 
           Navigated="webBrowser_Navigated" 
           IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading.IsFalse}">
       </phone:WebBrowser>
   </Grid>`
   ```

   And while intellisense detects `behaviours`, `WebBrowserBehaviors`, and `BindableSource` it displays the following error message:

   `Error  1   DependencyProperty MyApp.Behaviors.WebBrowserBehaviors. BindableSource cannot be set on an object of type Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.`
2. Problem 2:

   Originally I had `<WebBrowser Source={Binding CurrentUri}>`

   but when I try to use `behaviors:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource="{Binding ...}"`

   intellisense doesn't show me any of my ViewModels property which are binded to my layoutRoot.

   I don't know if it's related to problem 1, but I thought I'd better mention it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your base type is incorrect.  It should be changed from "typeof(bool)" to "typeof(string)".

Comment: Hi, I just figured it out :). There is actually another problem with the definition.

Comment: Great.  I was just leading you towards a solution.  I noticed a lot of stuff I would've done differently.  :D, good luck.

Comment: Thanks. My solution worked great, but I'd be interested in what else you would have change. Always interested in learning more and better code :)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 issues with my DependencyProperty definition.

1. The `propertyType` parameter is invalid. Its base type is set to `typeof(bool)` when it should be `typeof(string)`
2. The `ownerType` parameter is invalid. Its base type set to `typeof(WebBrowserBehaviors)` when it should be `typeof(WebBrowser)`

So the DependencyProperty will look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
    "BindableSource",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(WebBrowser),
    new PropertyMetadata(BindableSourcePropertyChanged)
    );
```

Point 2 is actually the one creating the error described in my title but point 1 would have thrown an error or validation would have failed when trying to set the property to a string.