# WebBrowser in WPF with bound Source attached property navigates only once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, browser, data-binding

I am using a WebBrowser control with an attached property to bind to an `Uri` property in ViewModel as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263551/databind-the-source-property-of-the-webbrowser-in-wpf)

It works, but on each start of the application the browser navigates exactly once. On second and further tries it just becomes empty (transparent, not white).

ViewModel:

```
public Uri BrowserUri
    {
        get
        {
            return GetBrowserUri();                
        }
    }
```

Attached property:

```
public class AttachedUri
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedUriProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedUri", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedUri), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, AttachedUriPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetAttachedUri(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AttachedUriProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachedUri(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AttachedUriProperty, value);
    }

    public static void AttachedUriPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {                
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
            {
                browser.NavigateToString("<html></html>"); // trying to refresh                    
                browser.Navigate(new Uri(uri));                    
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <controls:WebBrowser at:AttachedUri.AttachedUri="{Binding BrowserUri}" Navigating="PDFBrowser_OnNavigating"/>
```

As seen above, I also tried to see if `Navigating` event fires every time when I try to navigate. It does fire every time for `Navigate` but only once for `NavigateToString`.

I need the browser to navigate between different named destinations in a PDF file.

Comment: There is no notification mechanism that informs the Binding when the BrowserUri property changes. Your view model class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: My view model does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I see each new Uri get processed in AttachedUriPropertyChanged, it just doesn't seem to have any effect on the browser. The binding is meant as one-way only, from view model to browser, not back

Comment: One more thing I noticed: Calling Refresh() on browser always results in an exception.HRESULT E_FAIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to create a new browser in a static border each time I need to navigate.

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" at:AttachedUri.AttachedUri="{Binding BrowserUri}"/>
```

And code:

```
public static void AttachedUriPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = o as Border;            
        if (border != null)
        {                
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
            {
                Uri link = new Uri(uri);
                WebBrowser newBrowser = new WebBrowser();
                newBrowser.Navigate(link);
                border.Child = newBrowser;
            }                
        }
    }
```